# How Sencha cmd is worked using jetty web server and jsp file is not recognized by sencha cmd

Tags: java, jsp, cmd, extjs6

I have created **ExtJS6** app with **sencha cmd** and I added **JSP** file to app and try to run application, but it is not recognized by **sencha cmd**, I want to know how can I integrate **JSP** and **Java** action with **sencha** app.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can add `JSP file in your Sencha Application`..Try moving code from index.html fiel to your JSP file..say home.JSP file.Copy your index.html file code into home.jsp file and from JAVA call that JSP file initially.Hope this work for you